# How can I put two strings in one print function?

Tags: python, string, printing

I want to put two strings and one var in one print function is it possible for example:
print('Your Name is' +name 'I like it!')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is called string concatenation. You can add combine strings with variables like this:

```
print("My name is " + first_name + "." + greeting)
```

Or you could format it like this:

```
print(f"My name is {first_name}. {greeting}")
```

Comment: Or you can use `print("My name is ", first_name, ". ", greeting, sep="")`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a format string, like so:

```py
print(f'Your name is {name}. I like it!')
```